# Bootstrap inputs css issues

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, angular4-forms

[image: Css issue image]

```
 <div class="form-group">
           <label for="AppName">Application Name</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="AppName" id="AppName" tabindex="1" #aName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="application.AppName" required maxlength="50" />                               
   </div>
```

Q: From the above html code i've got this lines to the left side of the input text box which is visible only in IE. And this problem is not shown in some machines with the same IE but it shows in some machines. Can any suggest what the heck with this bootstrap.

Comment: What version of IE?

Comment: Its IE 11. With the same version in windows 10 i'm unable to see this issue. But with the same version in IOS i'm able to see this. dont know what the reason

Answer (score 0):

For IE only you can use following code snipt example for Style.

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style>
    .your class {
            style  attributes;
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Are you saying that we can not use bootstrap built in styles ?

Comment: You can, but this works for all relative updates for IE.

Comment: Can you please give which style attributes i need to write to avoid those lines..